# How to check if route exists in FOSJSRoutingBundle

Tags: javascript, symfony

```
var possibleRoute = "crm_finance_report";  
var route = Routing.generate( possibleRoute );
```

This throw an error, how can I check if the route exists before?

The error is because the route doesn't exist, but I want to show a message or something in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things you can check:

- What does the error say?

Also:

- Are the routes marked as exposed?:

  ```
  options:
      expose: true
  ```
- Did you `dump` your routes?: `bin/console fos:js-routing:dump`
- Did you add the JS routing scripts to your HTML?:

  ```
  <script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {'callback': 'fos.Router.setData'}) }}"></script>
  ```

Definitely read the [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md).

---

**EDIT:** To speficially check if a route does not exist using JavaScript, you can do two things:

1. Call `Routing.getRoutes()` and check if your route exists.
2. Call `Routing.getRoute(...)` and catch an error (which is throws if the route `...` does not exist).

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself, the thing is the route doesn't exist, with other routes is working fine. I want to know how to check before. To show a message or whatever.

Comment: I think this could work, thanks. Anyway is Routing, not Router.

Comment: Someone opened an issue but the proposed PR was never implemented - https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/issues/189 . You could try that method, or even [write a custom Twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) as a function and pass in the FOSJSRoutingBundle as a service to determine if the route exists

Answer (score 0):

Use the console tools. In Symfony2 it is:

```
app/console debug:router
```

And in Symfony3 it is:

```
bin/console debug:router
```

Eventually you have to prepend `php`, if it doesn't work like in the above examples, depending on the operating system you are using.

Comment: I need to check in javascript, to show a message or something.

Comment: Sorry, I saw it is tagged with symfony2 and thought that you don't know which routes exist before. With "before" I was thinking on the server side.